# How to turn an objects of arrays into arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object of arrays say

```
obj_of_arr = {a : [1,2], b:["foo","bar"]}
```

and I want to turn it into the equivalent array of objects

```
arr_of_obj = [{a:1,b:"foo"},{a:2,b:"bar"}]
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this? I can "brute force" this but I want to know if there is an elegant way. If it involves jQuery it's fine.

Comment: Could you accept this answer? It would help other users with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do it with two loops?

**Note:** If this is the "brute force" way you talked about, then I don't know how to help you. Even if there's some jQuery (or other framework) function that does this, it probably uses a similar construct internally, as those frameworks usually don't have any magical powers that let them be faster or more efficient.

[**Preview (JSBin)**](http://jsbin.com/utEpILE/1/edit?js,console)

```js
function obj_to_arr(obj_of_arr) {
    var objects = [];

    for (var prop in obj_of_arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj_of_arr[prop].length; i++) {
            if (typeof(objects[i]) != "object") {
                objects[i] = {};
            }
            objects[i][prop] = obj_of_arr[prop][i];
        }
    }

    return objects;
}

const obj_of_arr = {a : [1,2], b:["foo","bar"]};
console.log(obj_to_arr(obj_of_arr));
```